# What is the spatial covariance algorithm?

Tags: covariance, spatial, random-field, covariance-function

Given a realization of a spatial random field, what is the algorithm to determine the spatial covariance, or the covariance function of the spatial lag?
Many thanks.

Comment: There are many.  A general collection of procedures goes under the name "variography," which you ought to search and study.

Comment: Thank you. I've found many articles and books on the topic, but I never found algorithms, instead I found many formulas.

Comment: Algorithms were developed beginning in the 1980's: [see this Google Scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C11&q=cressie+variogram&btnG=) for publications by one noted researcher.  If you might be looking for software solutions, see the "geostatistics" section on the [CRAN spatial data view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) for some pointers.